# Heroku classpath FileNotFound Exception

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, filenotfoundexception

**Context:** I have a Spring Boot application in which I want to send an e-mail to a user after it's account has been created. I have a newUser.html file in my resources folder in which I edit the "e-mail" and "password" field, and a few images that I want to send along. I do this using Jsoup:

```
@Override
public void sendUserCreatedMail(CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    //Get JavaMailSender
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = mailMapper.mapMailSender();

    //set the html elements with Jsoup
    Document doc = buildHtmlDocument(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("html/newUser.html").getPath());
    Element loginElement = doc.getElementById("login");
    Element passwordElement = doc.getElementById("password");

    loginElement.text("Login: " + createUserRequest.getEmail());
    passwordElement.text("Password: " + createUserRequest.getPassword());

    String html = doc.toString();

    // Add inline images, key + value
    Map<String, String> inlineImages = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/rea-logo-rond.png").getPath() != null){
        //Get Email images Path
        String logoPath = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/rea-logo-rond.png").getPath();
        inlineImages.put("logo", logoPath);
    }

    //Create email instance  & send mail
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailMapper.mapCreateUserRequestToSender(createUserRequest, inlineImages, html);
    mailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

This all works fine when running the program in my IDE.
When I run this on Heroku however, I get a "FileNotFound" exception:

```
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/app/rea-backend/target/rea-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/html/newUser.html (No such file or directory)]
```

I have stumbled upon this [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292481/heroku-springboot-classpathresource-get-filenotfoundexception), but it doesn't have a suitable solution for my case.
I wish I could just resort to saving the newUser.html as a Blop in my DB, and getting it each time (though it's not really a good work-around..); BUT the way the "Document" constructor works, is it needs a PATH string of the File you are trying to use, not the actual file itself... The same goes for the images that are needed.

There has to be another way to access the files in your resources folder using Heroku?
Or am I doing something wrong? I don't understand why it works on local, but not on Heroku.

Choosing another platform than Heroku is not an option at this point.

Comment: Because it isn't a `java.util.File` but a resource. A `java.util.File` has to represent a physical file on the filesystem, when it is packaged as a jar that image isn't a physical file anymore but just a resource inside a jar. Hence this won't work. You need to use an `InputStream` and write the bytes as attachment.

Comment: Okay, but the MimeMessage i'm using takes a Map<String, String> of "inlineImages" which holds the name and the PATH to the file, not the InputStream itself. So what you are saying is I should resee my whole mail sending implementation? I feel like there has to be a way.. if this isn't meant to work then why create MimeMessage to receive only path of the file but not the file itself?

Comment: The `MimeMessage` has other means to include inline images, so yes you have to rethink your logic as this will simply not work. I would suggest using the Spring MimeMessageHelper, which has various `addInline` methods taking different elements, one of them is an `InputStreamSource` or even a `Resource` (Which you could then use with a `ClassPathResource`).

Comment: When you just can't see it, you need someone to point you to the right direction.. Thanks alot man, you've been a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

As M.Deinum pointed out, there is no way to do this, cause when these files are packaged as a jar, those images arent physical files anymore, just a resource inside a jar.

I got a solution by following M. Deinum's advice and using the messageHelper.addInline() (for the images) and InputStream for the html file. Stuff is working great now!

```
@Override
public void sendUserCreatedMail(CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    //Get JavaMailSender
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = mailMapper.mapMailSender();

    //Create email instance  & send mail
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailMapper.mapCreateUserRequestToMimeMessage(createUserRequest, mailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage());
    mailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage);
}

public MimeMessage mapCreateUserRequestToMimeMessage(CreateUserRequest createUserRequest, MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    //set meta data using "MimeMessageHelper"
    MimeMessageHelper helper = getMessageHelper(mimeMessage, createUserRequest.getEmail(),"Uw Real Estate Academy Account", "Real Estate Academy <" + this.emailConfiguration.getUsernameInfo()+">");

    String htmlMessage = buildCreateUserRequestHtmlDocument("html/newUser.html", createUserRequest);
    InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/rea-logo-rond.png");
    helper.setText(htmlMessage, true);
    helper.addInline("logo", new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)), "image/png");

    return mimeMessage;
}

public String buildCreateUserRequestHtmlDocument(String filePath, CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputStream, "UTF-8", "https://www.realestateacademy.be");

    Element loginElement = doc.getElementById("login");
    Element passwordElement = doc.getElementById("password");

    loginElement.text("Login: " + createUserRequest.getEmail());
    passwordElement.text("Password: " + createUserRequest.getPassword());

    return doc.toString();
}
```